# With identical field item converting into array of value

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am trying to map an array with key like below

```
const data =    [{
          "_id": "5f0ffb96d67d70c1a3b143e7",
          "name": "USER",
          "type": "CUSTOM",
          "origin": "USER",
          "conditions": [{
            "_id": "5f0ffb96d67d70c1a3b143e8",
            "field": "status",
            "value": "Nomita",
            "operator": "equal"
          }, {
            "_id": "5f0ffb96d67d70c1a3b143e9",
            "field": "current_status",
            "value": "ACTIVE",
            "operator": "equal"
          }, {
            "_id": "5f0ffb96d67d70c1a3b143ea",
            "field": "user_group_uuid",
            "value": "d12s0a7c-11ac-7abf-bl03-f0b70e26f8f2",
            "operator": "equal"
          }, {
            "_id": "5f0ffb96d67d70c1a3b143eb",
            "field": "user_group_uuid",
            "value": "20348751-dcaa-4227-a0ff-912b27180aee",
            "operator": "equal"
          }]
        }]
```

The above is the input.

```
const filters_data = { ...data[0] }
const filters_mapping = (array, keyField) =>
    array.reduce((obj, item) => {
            obj[item[keyField]] = item
            return obj
        }, {})
const filter_items = filters_mapping(filters_data.conditions,'field');
```

From this code I am getting

```
{ user_status:
   { _id: 5f0ffb96d67d70c1a3b143e8,
     field: 'status',
     value: 'Nomita',
     operator: 'equal' },
  current_status:
   { _id: 5f0ffb96d67d70c1a3b143e9,
     field: 'current_status',
     value: 'ACTIVE',
     operator: 'equal' },
  user_group_uuid:
   { _id: 5f0ffb96d67d70c1a3b143eb,
     field: 'user_group_uuid',
     value: 'd12s0a7c-11ac-7abf-bl03-f0b70e26f8f2',
     operator: 'equal' } }
```

But I actually want something like this, that maps the `value` in array when the field is similar.

```
{ user_status:
       { _id: 5f0ffb96d67d70c1a3b143e8,
         field: 'status',
         value: 'Nomita',
         operator: 'equal' },
      current_status:
       { _id: 5f0ffb96d67d70c1a3b143e9,
         field: 'current_status',
         value: 'ACTIVE',
         operator: 'equal' },
      user_group_uuid:
       { _id: 5f0ffb96d67d70c1a3b143eb,
         field: 'user_group_uuid',
         value: ['d12s0a7c-11ac-7abf-bl03-f0b70e26f8f2','20348751-dcaa-4227-a0ff-912b27180aee'],
         operator: 'equal' } }
```

this should happen only when there's multiple fields are available or else, it would return normal string only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ciao, I'm using your code but before reduce I combine value with same field value.
Here working example:

```js
const data =    [{
          "_id": "5f0ffb96d67d70c1a3b143e7",
          "name": "USER",
          "type": "CUSTOM",
          "origin": "USER",
          "conditions": [{
            "_id": "5f0ffb96d67d70c1a3b143e8",
            "field": "status",
            "value": "Nomita",
            "operator": "equal"
          }, {
            "_id": "5f0ffb96d67d70c1a3b143e9",
            "field": "current_status",
            "value": "ACTIVE",
            "operator": "equal"
          }, {
            "_id": "5f0ffb96d67d70c1a3b143ea",
            "field": "user_group_uuid",
            "value": "d12s0a7c-11ac-7abf-bl03-f0b70e26f8f2",
            "operator": "equal"
          }, {
            "_id": "5f0ffb96d67d70c1a3b143eb",
            "field": "user_group_uuid",
            "value": "20348751-dcaa-4227-a0ff-912b27180aee",
            "operator": "equal"
          }]
        }]
        
const conditions_combined = _.uniqWith(data[0].conditions, function(a, b) {
  if (a.field === b.field) {
    b.value += ', ' + a.value;
    b.value = b.value.split(",");
    return true;
  }
});
data[0].conditions = conditions_combined;
const filters_data = { ...data[0] };
const filters_mapping = (array, keyField) =>
    array.reduce((obj, item) => {
            obj[item[keyField]] = item
            return obj
        }, {})
const filter_items = filters_mapping(filters_data.conditions,'field');
console.log(filter_items);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Explanation: I'm using _.uniqWith from lodash to combine value with same field value.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible soluce.

Your code doesn't handle the case where the key already exists.

```js
const data = [{
  "_id": "5f0ffb96d67d70c1a3b143e7",
  "name": "USER",
  "type": "CUSTOM",
  "origin": "USER",
  "conditions": [{
    "_id": "5f0ffb96d67d70c1a3b143e8",
    "field": "status",
    "value": "Nomita",
    "operator": "equal"
  }, {
    "_id": "5f0ffb96d67d70c1a3b143e9",
    "field": "current_status",
    "value": "ACTIVE",
    "operator": "equal"
  }, {
    "_id": "5f0ffb96d67d70c1a3b143ea",
    "field": "user_group_uuid",
    "value": "d12s0a7c-11ac-7abf-bl03-f0b70e26f8f2",
    "operator": "equal"
  }, {
    "_id": "5f0ffb96d67d70c1a3b143eb",
    "field": "user_group_uuid",
    "value": "20348751-dcaa-4227-a0ff-912b27180aee",
    "operator": "equal"
  }]
}];

const mutatedData = data[0].conditions.reduce((tmp, {
  _id,
  field,
  value,
  operator,
}) => {
  // Handle the case where the field already exists
  if (tmp[field]) {
    tmp[field].value = [
      ...(tmp[field].value instanceof Array ?
        tmp[field].value : [tmp[field].value]),

      value,
    ];

    return tmp;
  }

  // Handle the case where the field doesn't exist yet
  tmp[field] = {
    _id,
    field,
    value,
    operator,
  };

  return tmp;
}, {});


console.log(mutatedData);
```

---

**Condensed version**

```js
const data = [{
  "_id": "5f0ffb96d67d70c1a3b143e7",
  "name": "USER",
  "type": "CUSTOM",
  "origin": "USER",
  "conditions": [{
    "_id": "5f0ffb96d67d70c1a3b143e8",
    "field": "status",
    "value": "Nomita",
    "operator": "equal"
  }, {
    "_id": "5f0ffb96d67d70c1a3b143e9",
    "field": "current_status",
    "value": "ACTIVE",
    "operator": "equal"
  }, {
    "_id": "5f0ffb96d67d70c1a3b143ea",
    "field": "user_group_uuid",
    "value": "d12s0a7c-11ac-7abf-bl03-f0b70e26f8f2",
    "operator": "equal"
  }, {
    "_id": "5f0ffb96d67d70c1a3b143eb",
    "field": "user_group_uuid",
    "value": "20348751-dcaa-4227-a0ff-912b27180aee",
    "operator": "equal"
  }]
}];

const mutatedData = data[0].conditions.reduce((tmp, {
  _id,
  field,
  value,
  operator,
}) => (tmp[field] = tmp[field] ? ((tmp[field].value = [
  ...(tmp[field].value instanceof Array ?
    tmp[field].value : [tmp[field].value]),

  value,
]) && tmp[field]) : {
  _id,
  field,
  value,
  operator,
}) && tmp, {});

console.log(mutatedData);
```